# iOS - Segue from a tableViewController to a ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView Controller placed in a tab bar view, once the user chooses one of the table cells, I want to take him to a view controller with details about that cell.  I created the view and all, but I am not sure how can I send an object from the table view controller to the view controller so I can display it's details. I did the segue by control dragging from my prototype cell to the view controller and it works, it's just about getting the object. Please help :)

Best,
Anas

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SomeView") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```

or something like

```
if segue!.identifier == "Details" {
    let cellViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    cellViewController.something = self.dataTable[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a UINavigationController to do that.

In your tableview delegate, when you tab the row, show your view controller here

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

But you will need to have a navigation controller to wrap your table view controller first. You can also do this in storyboard by dragging a navigation controller to storyboard, by default a table view controller is attached. And link your navigation controller to your tab bar controller as a tab.